# cd: permission denied: binutils-2.21.1

Tags: debian, permissions, cd-command

I'm following [Tools Used in 6.828](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2014/tools.html) to configure.

```
$ sudo tar xjf binutils-2.21.1.tar.bz2
```

generate folder `binutils-2.21.1`

```
$ cd binutils-2.21.1
cd: permission denied: binutils-2.21.1
$ sudo cd binutils-2.21.1
sudo: cd: command not found
```

Permissions of this folder's Properties show me I have `Read & Write` access.

How could I go into this folder (and build it)?

```
$ ls -l
drwxrwx--- 18  500  500     4096 Aug 24  2011 binutils-2.21.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 18997755 Aug 26  2011 binutils-2.21.1.tar.bz2
drwxr-xr-x 21  500  500     4096 Apr 26 20:40 gcc-4.6.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 30117877 Jun 27  2011 gcc-core-4.6.1.tar.bz2
drwxr-xr-x 15 1001 root     4096 Apr 26 21:55 gmp-5.0.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2024576 Apr 26 21:39 gmp-5.0.2.tar.bz2 
drwxr-xr-x  6 rahn rahn     4096 Apr 26 22:00 mpc-0.9
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   565953 Jan 19 05:11 mpc-0.9.tar.gz 
drwxr-xr-x  9 rahn rahn     4096 Apr 26 21:57 mpfr-3.1.4
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1279284 Mar  6 21:43 mpfr-3.1.4.tar.bz2
```

Debian 8.4, zsh

Comment: Probably because you used `sudo` to extract the tarball, your ordinary user doesn't have the required *execute* permission in order to traverse the directory

Comment: @steeldriver `tar` can't be done without `sudo`. BTW, `sudo tar` works for other tar file

Comment: Sure `tar` can be done without `sudo` **if** you place the tarball in an appropriate directory. The permissions on the extracted directory appear to be slightly unusual (`drwxrwx---`) - perhaps "the other tar file" extracts with `r-x` permissions for `other` which is why you can cd to that even though it's root-owned.

Comment: Being able to enter/traverse a directory requires *execute* permissions. Having read/write permission will not allow you to view a directory's contents. Please show us the output of `ls -ld binutils-2.21.1` to show us exactly what permissions you have on that directory.

Comment: @steeldriver `binutils-2.21.1.tar.bz2` is placed in `~/Desktop/MIT/xv6`. I do `tar xjf` to 2 previous tar file and they both work well. What is **appropriate directory** for Debian for such lab work?

Comment: `~/Desktop/MIT/xv6` sounds fine **however** if you already used `sudo tar` to extract it then it will be root-owned: you should be able to restore appropriate ownership using `sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn) binutils-2.21.1`. Or just start over **without** `sudo`.

Comment: @steeldriver If chown fixes it, you should make that an answer. I don't want to steel it from you when you wrote it.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, it works! But, I don't understand why I have to do this? Might it because I mistakenly do `sudo wget` to download the file that affect the permission?

Answer (score 2):

cd is builtin command:

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

You can't run it via `sudo`
You can use the following command:

```
sudo -i
```

Comment: After `sudo -i`, I see nothing in `~/Desktop` and my `zsh` hightlight gone.

Comment: @Rahn , Yes, because you login into root user.

Comment: use `pwd` command. It's abbriviation of "Print Working Directory".